# Unable to sort list on the basis of custom setting value

Tags: apex, salesforce-id

I have created a customsetting having a field (Sort__c) to be used as index.However unable to sort the list and manage on the basis of that record.

```
class Axiom {
    public string Sorted{
            get;
            set;
        }
public Axiom(){

}
        public String Name {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public Boolean IsEditable {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public Boolean IsRequired {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public String SortVal {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public String Field {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public String title {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public map < String, List < String >> PickListVal {
            get;
            set;
        }


        }



        List <String> picklistValue = new List <String> ();

        List <Axiom> Vcloud = new List <Axiom> ();
            Map<String, customsettingValue__c> cs = customsettingValue__c.getAll();
            List<String> keys = new List<String>(cs.keySet());
            keys.sort();
            for (String key : keys) {
                customsettigValue__c DivValue = cs.get(key);

                Axiom DivFieldvcloud = new Axiom();
                DivFieldvcloud.PickListVal = new map <String, List < String >> ();

                if (DivValue.vision__c == 'XYZ') {
                    DivFieldvcloud.SortVal=DivValue.Sort__c;
                    DivFieldvcloud.Name = DivValue.Name__c;

                    Vcloud.add(DivFieldvcloud);
}
}


            list<Axiom> tempLst = Vcloud.clone();//backup your collection
Vcloud.clear();
            for(Axiom visVal :tempLst)
            {
system.debug('visVal.SortVal val'+visVal.SortVal);
            if(visVal.SortVal!=null)
            {
            system.debug('value'+tempLst[integer.valueof(visVal.SortVal)]);
            Vcloud.add(tempLst[integer.valueof(visVal.SortVal)]);

            }
            system.debug(' Vcloud value'+Vcloud);

            }
            system.debug(' Vcloud final'+Vcloud);
```

Comment: putting uppercase to your variables first characters (like Vcloud, DivValue...) and lowercase to your types first characters ( like customsettigValue__c, map ) doesn't help to read the code. Especially when you also do the opposite in the same code. That being said I can see nowhere an atetmpt to sort your list by Sort__c. The getAll() method, I may be wrong but I believe, doesn't send you a Map with the Sort__c as keys, does it ? The only sort method however sorts those keys...

Comment: I don't understand your question e.g. "having a field (Sort__c) to be used as index". Please add more explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your Sort__c field is unique, you could use this code, otherwise you would have to adapt it and deal with a `Map<String, List<Axiom>> mapToSort` to prevent overwritting values in the first loop :

```
Map<String, Axiom> mapToSort = new Map<String, Axiom>();
for (Axiom ax : Vcloud)
{
    mapToSort.put(ax.sortVal, ax);
}
List<String> keys = new List<String>(mapToSort.keySet());
keys.sort();
List<Axiom> listSorted = new List<Axiom>();
for (String key : keys)
{
    listSorted.add(mapToSort.get(key));
}
```

Comment: Thanks @emmanuel But I am facing the below error Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void sort() from the type Set<String> seems wrong with the method

Comment: Exact Sets can't be sorted, so I edit my answer to change it. In addition I tried to assign a Set to a List :~)

Comment: Still throwing the exception COMPILE ERROR: Illegal assignment from void to List<String>
Seems sort returns void :(

Comment: true : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_list.htm#apex_methods_system_list. Sorry, I edit it again

Answer (score 1):

As you can do a custom sorting of all the results or if you don't want to go that route then a simple SOQL will solve your issue as well.

```
[SELECT ID FROM customsettingValue__c ORDER BY Sort__c]
```

using SOQL's native order by functionality you can easily sort the records.